Excel MID function
I have 2 MID function formulas that I use to extract data on a specific cell string on an excel spreadsheet which work perfectly fine for me when used separately in different columns, but I would like to use these formulas together with an "OR" logic on the same column since my data could be either or, and will never have both conditions on a single cell, please assist
=MID(C4, FIND("ML", C4), LEN(C4) - FIND("ML", C4) + 1)
=MID(C4, FIND("PL", C4), LEN(C4) - FIND("PL", C4) + 1)
I have exhausted all the options that I could think of, but nothing seems to work
Sample data below:
xyz drt ML0000123456
hrz sd fri PL0000987456
asdfghg ML5236987412
lhkghibkjn PL1236540001

Your expected behavior is unclear, please clarify. MID extracts a string and you cannot OR two substring operations. Do you want to use the first MID if the string can be found (FIND) in the cell? What do you want to happen if the cell contains both prefixes?

Not sure if you really need to use MID, if you have Office 365 this seems to suffice: =TEXTAFTER(A1:A4," ",-1)

Try one of the followings:


=IFERROR(REPLACE(A1,1,SUM(IFERROR(FIND({"ML","PL"},A1),0))-1,""),"")


Or,
=IFNA(TEXTAFTER(A1,TEXTBEFORE(A1,{"ML","PL"})),"")


Or, a formula like this would be better:
=LET(
     a, TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),
     FILTER(a,(OR(LEFT(a,2)={"ML";"PL"}))*(LEN(a)=12)*(ISERR(--a)),""))


